# Pre-1995 movie which involved being stuck on a futuristic island

Tags: story-identification, movie

Back in about 1995, I remember watching a movie with some older kids. The movie was on late and before the movie ended, I had to leave and go to bed.

I never saw the end of the movie and have no idea what it was called.

From memory, the movie involved being stuck on a futuristic island and needing to leave. The main guy had met an inventor while there who was trying to build a boat or plane or something like that to help them get away.

The movie was on TV I think so I presume it probably had a release date of 1994 or earlier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are talking about the truly awesome [*Escape from Absolom / No Escape*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Escape_(1994_film)) movie (1994).

[image: Poster]

This involved an island of prisoners split into two groups (roughly speaking, goodies and baddies). The main character John Robbins is a combat expert.

One of the "goodies" is an inventor who tries to make a boat to avoid the guards radar to escape the island.

Comment: Amazing - thanks so much. Will now see if it is on Netflix...

Comment: @JonWinstanley: enjoy it, I loved it!

Comment: Yeah -good flick with a great ending, IMHO.

Comment: I think I remember this one. It had one of the main guys killed by a log trap near the end, had one of the good guys (or maybe the mole) in a trap where letting go of the cord (maybe held in his teeth) would trigger his death, requiring him to exhaust himself holding off death?